# Showing a property of a curvature tensor in $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

Consider $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. I need to show that if $$R_{ijkl} = -g(R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k,\partial_l)$$

is a curvature tensor in $S^2$ and $g$ is a metric also in $S^2$, then

$$R_{ijkl} = k(g_{ik}g_{jl} - g_{il}g_{jk})$$

where $k$ is the curvature of $S^2$.

**Attempt:** I managed to show that $R_{ijkl} = -R_{jikl}$ and $$R_{ijkl} + R_{jkil} + R_{kilj} = 0 $$

(Bianchi's First Identity)

I couldn't figure out though how to get that identiy. I was thingking maybe use that $R_{ijkl} = g_{im}R^{m}_{ijk}$.

**Edit:** I got one more step using the properties above

$$R_{ijkl} = \frac{1}{2}\Big(R_{jkil}+R_{kilj}-R_{ikjl}-R_{kjli}\Big)$$

Any help, please? I've been searching and found that this could be derived from Bianchi's Identities.

Comment: Where are you using anything about its being the sphere sitting in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: I'm not, that's the problem. I know for example that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the Christoffel symbols are zero, so $R_{ijkl} = 0$.

Comment: First, for a surface, only $R_{1212}$ (and its $\pm$ cousins by symmetry) is nonzero. You need to parametrize (give a chart for) the sphere and calculate!

Comment: I believe this was supposed to be independent of metric, no?

Comment: Absolutely NOT! A general ellipsoid (which is diffeo to a sphere) does not have constant curvature!

Comment: How come, the exercise would have given every metric this would work then.

Comment: "Therefore $k=1$" Not quite. This will only be true for some choices of $g$, e.g. the metric on the round sphere induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Ted above gives an example of a metric where $k\neq 1$.

Comment: I'm just writing the exercise as it was proposed.

Comment: The exercise as it was proposed was for the standard, round sphere in $\Bbb R^3$. I promise you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation 
$$R_{ijkl} = k(g_{ik}g_{jl} - g_{il}g_{jk})$$
is true of all 2 dimensional surfaces, not just $S^2$,
if you let the Gaussian curvature, $k$, vary over the surface.
$S^2$ just makes $k$ constant.

The proof primarily depends on the relationship between antisymetrization and the Levi-Civita tensor, $\varepsilon_{ij}$, in 2 dimensions
$$X_{[ij]} = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{kl} X_{kl} $$
and similarly for the contravarint case.

After that the proof follows from the symmetries of the Riemann tensor and the relationship with the Ricci scalar and Gaussian curvature.

The proof is a little more elegant for the mixed case form of the Riemann tensor, $R_{ij}{}^{kl}$.

$$ \begin{align}
R_{ij}{}^{kl} &= R_{[ij]}{}^{[kl]} & & \text{by the symmetries of $R$}\\
&=  (\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{mn}) (\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon^{kl} \varepsilon_{op}) R_{mn}{}^{op} & &\text{by the 2 dimensional property above}\\
&=  (\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{kl}) (\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon^{mn} \varepsilon_{op}) R_{mn}{}^{op}  & &\text{rearranging}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{kl} R_{mn}{}^{[mn]} & &\text{2 dimensional property again}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{kl} R_{mn}{}^{mn} & & \text{by the symmetries of $R$}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{ij} \varepsilon^{kl} R & &\text{definition of Ricci scalar}\\
&= g_{[i}{}^k g_{j]}{}^{l} R & &\text{2 dimensional property again}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(g_{i}{}^{k}g_{j}{}^{l} - g_{j}{}^{k}g_{i}{}^{l}) R & & \text{definition of antisymmetrization}\\
&=  k(g_{i}{}^{k}g_{j}{}^{l} - g_{j}{}^{k}g_{i}{}^{l}) & & \text{since }k = \frac{1}{2}R\\
\end{align}$$

This proof look much neater in Penrose graphical notation.
I originally came up with this proof using Penrose graphical notation while working on a [tensor proof of the hairy ball theorem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71613/12306).
Unfortunately I have not found a good way of producing graphical notation for online use.

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks.